# How to estimate the time for creating a zipfile in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, zip

I've a method for creating zip file in my project and its working perfectly. I want to know is there any way to estimate the approximate time for creating that zip file.I know about `StopWatch`  but I dont think I can use that for my requirement. Any ideas????

Comment: We don't know what technology you're using to create the zip file. That would be helpful to know. But most likely you'll just have to zip a few files and record the amount of time it took to run.

Comment: Are you trying to display a status or do you really want to store these predictions/estimates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really impossible to answer.

The amount of time a ZIP process will need depends on many factors, for instance:

1. The compressability of the file(s) to compress. Point in case: XML files zip very nicely, MP3 files hardly at all.
2. The amount of files to compress.
3. The algorithm/implementation you use.
4. Whether the Pc you are using is also doing other work (especially I/O).
5. ...

The best you can do is ZIP a portion of the total data (say, 10%), then extrapolate to get an estimated time, then re-evaluate that estimate, say, every 10% of data or so.